# Understanding a boolean's role in a memory game "time checker"+"play again" functions (js)

Tags: javascript, boolean

I have an oral test about a js memory card game code, and as I do understand the play again and time checker functions themselves, I don't understand the role of the 'gamestart' boolean in making it work. the code looks like this - first of all :

```
var gameStart = false
```

as a global variable.

then come three functions : one for a time checker feature, second for a play again feature and third for a card-clicked basic function (I paste only the relevant part of the card-clicked function as it's long). :

```
setBestTime();

function timechecker() {
  timer = setInterval(function() {
    if (second < 60) { 
      second++;
    }

    if (second == 60) {
      min++;
      second = 0;
    }

    if (min == 60) {
      hour++;
      min = 0;
    }

    var new_hour = hour < 10 ? "0"+hour : hour;
    var new_min = min < 10 ? "0"+min : min;
    var new_second = second < 10 ? "0"+second : second;
    bestTime = new_hour+":"+new_min+":"+new_second;
    document.getElementById("timechecker").innerHTML = bestTime;
  }, 1000);

function playAgain() {
  flippedCouplesCount =0;
  shuffle();
  var cards = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
  for(var i=0; i<cards.length; i++){
      cards[i].classList.remove('flipped');
  }

  audioWin.pause();
  audioWin.currentTime = 0;
  document.getElementById("retry_class").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("timechecker-t").style.display = "none";
  gameStart = false;
  second = 0;
  min = 0;
  hour = 0;
}

function cardClicked(elCard) {
  if(!gameStart){
    timechecker();
    document.getElementById("timechecker-t").style.display = "block";
  }
  gameStart = true;
  if (isProccessing) {
      return;
  }
  isProccessing = true;
  if (elCard.classList.contains('flipped')) {
    isProccessing = false;
    return;
  }
}
```

Anyone can elaborate about the 'gamestart' boolean's role? 
Many tnx

Comment: It's pretty easy to read that from the conditional statement. The Boolean variable ensures the timer doesn't start automatically; seems like there is a game start button

Answer (score 1):

gameStart = 'are there any prior moves?'

If the game is set up, the gameStart is set to False. When the first card is clicked AND variable gameStart is False, the function timechecker() is called. 
timechecker() starts a clock that displays how long the game is running. This only has to be done once, at the start of the game, so after timechecker() is called, gameStart is set to True. This way timechecker() will not run again when another card is clicked, unless the function playAgain() is called.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, I think it just represents whether or not the game has started, in the playAgain() function, it is set to false to signify the game has not started

Then in the cardClicked function, once a card is clicked, we start the timer only if the game hasn't already started i.e when gameStart is false
Finally whether or not gameStart is false, once you click a card, gameStart is set to true

Hope this helped